# iPhone app entering background state and presenting a UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, timer, background, uialertview

If an app delegate receives the `-willResignActive` message and a UIAlertView is within 0.5 seconds of being shown, the app will present two alert views (one a duplicate) when it becomes active once more.

This is a problem, because if responding to the first alert view means there are no responders to the duplicate (likely!) the app will just crash.

Thoughts?

Comment: Not an answer, just a hint: if you still have the reference to the alert view you can get rid of it via [dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:)

Comment: @DarkDust: I can make an alert view static, that might work. I'd prefer not to. As you say, and I agree, even if it works it doesn't get to the heart of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have is to retain a static reference to a UIAlertView, dismiss (with clicked button index -1), release, and then allocate/init a new instance at the same address. This makes sure there's only ever one alert view scheduled or showing. If an alert view is already showing, ignore (or manage) the new request (failsafe popping to root view or some such).

It's not very satisfactory because `UIAlertView`s have nothing to do with the workings and shouldn't be static. In my mind at least.